# asp mvc change model data source to a web service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm starting up a new application and I'm trying to use asp.net MVC 4. The way that the network infrastructure has been setup means that the MVC application does not have access to the database directly. Instead I will be accessing a WCF web service to get all my data. This means that my list of usernames/user details is accessed through the WCF web service. I will be using RSync to push data to my site, so I wanted to make use of the inbuilt authentication stuff because RSync has commands to check if session authenticated:

```
if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
```

So my main question is how do I setup the authentication information using a webserive instead of a database? I noticed that the template uses:

`WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe)`

But this is because it is linked to a database with the following code:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

So I dont think I do it using this method unless I can override the WebSecurity.login method? all the other websecurity methods?

I dont think this is the right way to go. Instead I think i need to write my own security class and have the Users model having a static method called Login(username, password) that returns a user object. But then somehow I want to set the mvc (http session) user to logged in. So that when I use the Authorize attributes it will work. How do I set the http session user to authenticated?